# Why can't range over *[]Struct?

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, go

http://play.golang.org/p/jdWZ9boyrh

I am getting this error

```
    prog.go:29: invalid receiver type *[]Sentence ([]Sentence is an unnamed type)
    prog.go:30: cannot range over S (type *[]Sentence)
    [process exited with non-zero status]
```

when my function tries to receive structure array.

What does it mean by an unnamed type? Why can't it be named? I can name it outside function and also pass them as arguments with them being named.

It does not work. So I just passed []Sentence as an argument and solve the problem that I need to. But when passing them as arguments, I had to return a new copy.

I still think that it would be nice if I can just let the function receive the struct array and does not have to return anything.

Like below:

```
func (S *[]Sentence)MarkC() {
  for _, elem := range S {
    elem.mark = "C"
  }
}

var arrayC []Sentence
for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
  var new_st Sentence
  new_st.index = i
  arrayC = append(arrayC, new_st)
}
//MarkC(arrayC)
//fmt.Println(arrayC)
//Expecting [{0 C} {1 C} {2 C} {3 C} {4 C}] 
//but not working
```

It is not working either with []Sentence.

Is there anyway that I can make a function receive Struct array?

Comment: I would like to mention real quick that `*[]struct{}` is a *pointer* to a *range* of structs. Ranges are already *pointery* and so this is effectively a pointer to a pointer, which may help explain why you can't use `range` with it... It's different than a range of pointers to structs, which would be `[]*struct{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still learning Go but it seems that it wants the type named. You know, "array of sentences" - that is really an anonymous type. You just have to name it.

(also, use `for` or one-variable form of `range` to avoid copying elements (and discarding your changes))

```
type Sentence struct {
  mark string
  index int
}

type SentenceArr []Sentence

func (S SentenceArr)MarkC() {
  for i := 0; i < len(S); i++ {
    S[i].mark = "S"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but not working. Can you check this? http://play.golang.org/p/NX6lw31AWE

Comment: Apparently, `range` returns a copy of elements. Use `for` loop: http://play.golang.org/p/agcnt6jBgo

Comment: Ah, it's not `range` that copies elements. It's `for`. Because you have `:=` there, see? :)

Comment: Yes, just use one-variable form. `for i := range s` and then index into the array

Comment: Hint: go lang specification is awesome! http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements